# Avoid users from paying already paid item on Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm a Paypal newbie. I design a booking system that has already a cart on it. What I did is manually create a form that will send my variables to paypal. Everytime I click the paypal button, a new tab is opened for the user to process the payment. The problem is, the user can go back to the *still open page* (booking cart) and be able to click the button again. Do you have any idea on how to avoid this? There might be a variable to use that detects identical items, no?

P.S. I am using an IPN for back-end processes.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using PayPal Standard Shopping Cart buttons.  Unfortunately, what you describe is simply how those work.

If you want more control you'll need to switch to something else.  For example, you could build your own shopping cart for your site, and then use the [cart upload method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/) to send the cart order data to PayPal.

Beyond that, you could use the [Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) for more freedom and flexibility with your integration.  That would require more coding experience.